# How can i remove an element of a localStorage item after a given amount of time?

Tags: javascript, timer, timestamp, local-storage, settimeout

In localStorage I have

```
orders: [["ciccio", 5, "18:10:49"];["ciccio", 10, "18:10:54"];["ciccio", 20, "18:11:14"]]
```

5, 10, 20 are minutes, I want to remove that specific element after 5/10/20 minutes: the first one should be removed at 18:15, the second one at 18:20 and the last one at 18:31 and I also need to remove the item when it'll be empty (orders: []). How could I implement this with only javascript? I know I could use this

```
setTimeout(function () { .... }, x * 1000);
```

But I don't know how. Can someone help me please? Thanks!

Comment: What is the expected behavior if the user does not have the page open at 18:15, for example?

Comment: @JoseNuno if i open the page at 18:25 my item should look like this: orders[["ciccio", 20, "18:11:14!]], i need to remove them even if the page isn't opened, or at least remove them the first time the page is opened

Comment: I would just read the entries with a forEach loop every time you need them and see if the element has not expired. Then you continue to operate only with the filtered entries.